# How to test if an input contains a question mark?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a script that tests if an input contains a question mark, and if it does, changes some css.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `jQuery`:

```
if ($("#myinputbox").val().indexOf("?") != -1) {

    $("#someotherelement").css("color", "red");
    $(this).css("color", "green");

} else {

    alert("Doesn't contain a question mark");

}
```

Not using jQuery:

```
if (document.getElementById('myinputbox').value.indexOf("?") != -1) {

    document.getElementById("someotherelement").className += " NewClass";
    this.className += " NewClass";

} else {

    alert("Doesn't contain a question mark");

}
```

**UPDATE : Validating onKeyDown()**

```
$("#myinputbox").keydown(function() {

    if ($(this).val().indexOf("?") != -1) {

        $(this).css("color", "green");

    } else {

        $(this).css("color", "red");

    }

});
```

Comment: How could I do this realtime though, so as a user is typing in the input box?

Comment: Just hook the onChange event. I'm updating my response now.

Comment: Try adding: alert($(this).val()); just above the conditional. Does it fire?

Comment: above the if / then? no it doesn't fire.

Comment: however, if i switch the change to click, then it does fire.

Comment: the entire function actually works on "click"
 but not with change, and I need it realtime

Comment: Ahh, sorry, change .change to .keydown. Does that help?

Comment: FIXED!  Keydown is awesome as are you!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Validating with keydown() works, however the keydown event is firing before the character is actually entered in the textbox. Therefore once you put in a '?', you won't get the color change until the next key is pressed, firing the keydown(). If you change it to use keyup() it will fire right after the '?' is let go, changing the color immediately after it has been typed. You can test this out by alerting the value like Jesse suggested, the first letter you type in the text box will actually show an empty alert. Changing it to keyup() and using the alert test, you will see what was just typed in the textbox.